# Calibration intrinsics for iphone 7

Tags: iphone, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I have an iphone 7 and I'd like to develop an augmented reality application for it. Anyway I can't find a way to get the rear camera intrinsic parameters `fx, fy, cx, cy`.

Is there a way to get these parameters for my device if they're not documented?